# The default DisplayTemplates views of ASP.NET-MVC2 are not compiled

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-2

Some of the default DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplate views of ASP.NET-MVC2 are not compiled.

Why and what to do you do to get them fixed.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to change the project settings to compile views, and build the project?

Comment: It is not an build action. it's an action on the build server that validated the all the view are compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved this problem with remove the `System.Data.EntityState` from the views, which I don't use anyway.